# c++ .clang-format unwanted spaces

Tags: c++, clang-format

Having this code,

```
// some random spaces
int a =1;
std::cout<< a <<std::endl;
```

I want it to be formatted without unnecessary spaces. Something like this:

```
int a=1; // No spaces around the equal sign
std::cout<<a<<std::endl; // no spaces around flow redirectors
```

But the best I can get, using clang-format 7.0.1 (debian/buster) is:

```
int a= 1; // Unwanted space at right of the equal symbol!
std::cout << a << std::endl; // Unwanted space around all redirectors!
```

Can't find how to do it, in the documentation nor using https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/ . How can I remove such unwanted spaces?

Comment: Do you really find code more readable when you remove all space? Personally I find it a lot harder to read when everything is squished together like that.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Please exclude all discussion related to personal tastes. That's subjective and improductive. My question relates to an objective problem, the solution is not to change tastes to imitate yours.

Comment: Sorry, you don't get to dictate my comments.

Comment: In my experience, clang-format is – despite its many config options – actually quite opinionated in its formatting. I don't have experience with your specific request, but since there is a general consensus in the programming world that there should be spaces around operators, I don't expect that clang-format will support your usecase. Maybe you can wrap clang-format in script of your own. You could just parse comments and strings and then remove any space that is not between two alphanumerical characters.

Comment: I just checked and Artistic Style and GNU indent also don't support removing spaces around operators, they only add them.